# How to disable go linter in vscode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I simply want to disable all linting. At some point Visual Studio Code (VSCode) asked to update golang tools / settings, and it enabled linting.

I searched on Google, but I found only results about setting the linter or disabling specific warnings.

Comment: Enabling the linter is a _good_ thing. You should embrace it!

Comment: @Flimzy I partially found a solution by using staticcheck. It doesn't complain and underline lines for non functional matters (e.g. "serverIp should be serverIP")

Comment: That sort of complaint comes from `golint`, I believe. A better approach, though, is probably to use `golangci-lint`, and then disable the rules (or better: the specific instances) you want to disable, with a `// nolint` directive, for example.

Comment: or you could call your variable `serverIP`

Answer (score 3):

Go to your extension settings and replace the go.lintTool value to empty string

[image]

Tools like goimports also format the code so you can also check if other tools running or on save events that might be triggering these tools

Comment: Correct answer, but I hope nobody ever does this. Linting needs to happen more, not less.

Comment: @Flimzy I know; plus go provides a good linter and it makes universally all code written in go same format; One of the plus sides I think of go

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava It does not work. VSCode version 1.51.1 go version go1.15.5 linux/amd64 (snap ubuntu 20)

Comment: @GibezynuNu then you might have some other on save hook running linter; Also check any other tools in extension settings that can run linter

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava The only go extension installed is "Go". Settings.json has only `"go.alternateTools": { "go": "/snap/go/current/bin/go"  }` as a directive for Go and 4 other vscode editor settings.  The alternatTools directive is a workaround for an issue from https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/166#issuecomment-688000742

Comment: Linting is great but it's intolerable that it happens every single time you save if you have the decades-old habit of saving constantly. It keeps deleting lines that I am not using at the moment, but am about to use.

What's even more frustrating is how IDEs in general, with VSCode being no exception, make it ridiculously convoluted to configure these sorts of things. I've found two options that I would think should obviously turn this off, but of course it's something completely different.

I'm fine with linting, I just don't want it happening at every save.